# Are there any Stackoverflow like sites for Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

Are there any Stackoverflow like sites for Joomla?

I know that there is a site for Drupal on the StackExchange network. I was hoping that someone might know of a similar site for Joomla.

Comment: You could propose one on http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It looks like that there is a proposal under way. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers They need more questions to be voted up for it to start.